# Media 7.x-1 Library tab empty

Tags: 7, media

All of the sudden my media library tab becomes empty. I check the permissions and everything seems to be fine.

[image: library empty]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like when I updated the jquery update module I checked both administrative  and default version to use jquery 1.7. There is a known issue here [jQuery Update 7.x-2.4 makes Media 7.x-1.4's Library tab empty](https://www.drupal.org/node/2245641)[image: Jquery update]. When I changed the administrative pages to use 1.5 everything was ok again.

Answer (score 1):

**chane Alternate jQuery version for administrative pages**   [image]